# Transit Visa & Baggage

Tags: transit, luggage, transit-visas

I have an Indian Passport and also hold a US green card. I will be returning from India to US, via UK and changing terminals in London. I will be arriving at Terminal 5 from India and boarding my connecting US flight from terminal 2. Two questions:
1. Do i need a UK transit visa? 
2. What about bags? Since i will be arriving by British Airways in Terminal 5 and boarding United Airlines from terminal 2

Comment: @MichaelHampton Does that address the baggage question?

Comment: @cpast There's too many questions here anyway. The transit question gets asked all the time. And the baggage question isn't answerable without knowing how the ticket was booked.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is not one one ticket, because BA and UA (United Airlines) usually do not interline like this.

If it is separate tickets, you will need to exit through arrivals at T5 to collect your baggage and take the tube or bus over to T2 and re-check-in. As a US Permanent Resident you do not need a transit visa. BA will not interline baggage to UA (or other non-oneworld carriers) under this circumstance, although I suppose there is no harm in asking.

If this is on one ticket (you bought all the flights in the same transaction from the same place to create a single contract) then your baggage will be checked through to UA automatically. You may simply take the airside buses over to T2 when you arrive in T5. Follow the purple signs to Flight Connections: Terminal 2. You do not need to pass through immigration. You can obtain your UA boarding pass in Terminal 2.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. This is not a single ticket...2 seperate tickets. Does this mean i will have to pass thru Border Control?

Comment: @BalajiNaman BA policy is not to check baggage through to separate tickets, except onto their partners and other oneworld members (UA is neither). So if you are taking a checked bag, you will have to collect it and re-check it in London. However, if you ask very nicely at your origin, and have your UA itinerary to hand, it is possible you will be lucky and the bag will be checked through. If you are not taking a bag or it is checked through, you can go directly to Terminal 2. Otherwise you will have to exit through the UK Border to collect your bag.